# Storing extra data in developer express component cxTreeView

Tags: delphi, treeview, devexpress

I have a cxTreeView on a form displaying descriptions of some files. I would like to be able to have the option of clicking one of the descriptions and have the filename returned.
In order to do this I need to store some extra data in the treeview and that is my problem.

How do I do this:
Store both filename and description, display just the description but get the filename by doubleclicking?

Comment: I would like to help, but first of all and best you can do is to [`contact support`](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/) and second, if you ask some question using some non-standard Delphi component, try to always include the source where did you get that (ideally including its version). At this time I can't find in what component set is the `TcxTreeView` included, so at this time I can't help.

Comment: developer express has TcxTreeView and TdxTreeView.  Not sure on the differences between the two.

Comment: DevEpreess support is not always the best place to get ideas.

Comment: I can't tell you more about the source other than it is part of the full package I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a TcxTreeList for this task (if possible), if there is no urgent need to use a TcxTreeView. In a TcxTreeList you can add a new column and store the filename in it. Then make this column invisible.

If you must rely on a TcxTreeView, there is no option to directly store data, like strings, in the TTreeNodes. You can store a pointer to any object into the property "Data" of the TTreeNode.

Comment: -1 You can do what's needed in a tree view. A list control is not much good for displaying trees.

Comment: @David: I do not understand your -1 at all. A TcxTreeList is very much capable of storing and displaying trees. What is better depends on your kind of data to display, or not? If you want to STORE a Filename besides a description, it's maybe the best choice.

Comment: You are right. I assumed the presence of the word List meant that this was a list view. Sorry. Converted to upvote.

Comment: @Andreas:  I have never worked with the treelist so I don't know where to start right now.  Do you know of a sample code somewhere that I could have a look at and se how to do this?

Comment: @TLama: your example ist good, of course. I had not the time to make one myself. But I mentioned the Data-property...

Comment: @OZ8HP: If you only have to store one PChar into the TcxTreeView, you can use TLamas example. Its easy and nice. There are some good examples coming with the DevExpess components, if you want to use TcxTreeList.

Comment: I ended up with using the TreeList as Andreas suggested and it came out quite nice as well.
So for now the customer is happy :-)

Comment: @Andreas: you must have worked a bit with the TreeList and I was wondering if you have tried to save the state of the nodes (open/closed) and then load them again from file or variable when form is opened again.

Comment: I found a solution for the saving/restoring state

Answer (score 1):

In both answers here is mentioned that `TcxTreeView` uses standard [`TTreeNode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode) where, as Warren pointed in [`his answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169007/960757) as first, you can use the [`TTreeNode.Data`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.Data) property to store your data. I'll just complete these thoughts with an example.

***Update:***

The previous version of this post would work only for constant strings for whose the space is being allocated automatically. If you need to pass a variable into the [`TTreeNode.Data`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.Data) you have to allocate and release the memory by your own. Here is the example with using simple helper functions.

The `AddFileNode` helper function adds the node to the `Items` into the `ParentNode` with the name of the `FileDesc` and allocates the space and copy the passed `FileName` for the [`TTreeNode.Data`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.Data) by using the [`StrNew`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrNew) function.

When you need to modify the data, you should release (or better, but little bit complicated would be to reallocate) the allocated memory and allocate the space and copy the new value. For this you can use the `ChangeFileName` which disposes the string memory allocated before and allocates the space and copy the passed `FileName` value.

As I mentioned before you need to take care of the memory disposal by your own and for this there is the `OnDeletion` event the best place. So write the handler for this event where you'll release the memory allocated when adding the items.

```
function AddFileNode(Items: TTreeNodes; ParentNode: TTreeNode;
  const FileName, FileDesc: string): TTreeNode;
begin
  Result := Items.AddChildObject(ParentNode, FileDesc, StrNew(PChar(FileName)));
end;

function ChangeFileName(TreeNode: TTreeNode; const FileName: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Assigned(TreeNode.Data) then
  begin
    Result := True;
    StrDispose(PChar(TreeNode.Data));
    TreeNode.Data := StrNew(PChar(FileName));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := 'C:\FileName 1.xxx';
  AddFileNode(cxTreeView1.Items, nil, S, 'File 1');
  S := 'C:\FileName 2.xxx';
  AddFileNode(cxTreeView1.Items, nil, S, 'File 2');
end;

procedure TForm1.cxTreeView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  if Assigned(Node.Data) then
    StrDispose(PChar(Node.Data));
end;

procedure TForm1.cxTreeView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurrentPos: TPoint;
  CurrentNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  CurrentPos := cxTreeView1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  if (htOnItem in cxTreeView1.GetHitTestInfoAt(CurrentPos.X, CurrentPos.Y)) then
  begin
    CurrentNode := cxTreeView1.GetNodeAt(CurrentPos.X, CurrentPos.Y);
    if Assigned(CurrentNode) and Assigned(CurrentNode.Data) then
      ShowMessage(PChar(CurrentNode.Data));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I have tried this suggestion but I never got it to show other than some very strange data that I couldn't use for anything.

Comment: Fixed. The previous solution could work only for constants for whose the memory is allocated automatically. For passing variables to the `TTreeNode.Data` you need to allocate the memory space and copy the string value by yourself as well as release the memory when you delete the node.

Answer (score 0):

If the nodes are regular TTreeNode, you can use the Data:Pointer value in the Node object.

If the nodes in your tree are of type `TcxTreeListNode`, they contain the ability to store any data values you want.  WHen I look at the sources, I see these properties in the node-level:

```
property ValueCount: Integer read GetValueCount;
property Values[Index: Integer]: Variant read GetValue write SetValue;
```

Comment: -1: a TcxTreeView uses normal TTreeNodes as Items. You cannot store Values within. Thus my suggestion to use a TcxTreeList, which uses TcxTreeListNodes.